# Data fetched from mongodb displayed in console and not in browser

Tags: mongodb, express

```
collection.find({"topicname":topicname},function(err,result){ 
if(result){   
    console.dir("Success from database =\n"+result.toString());
    console.dir(result);
    console.log("This is it"+result);
    res.send("Hello "+result);
}
});
```

The result is displayed in console in Json format, but when fetched in the browser, it displays Hello [object Object]. 
Database used is MongoDb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send("Hello " + JSON.stringify(result));`

This converts the JSON object into a String and will then render it appropriately on your page when concatenating with another String as you are doing.

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)